# Custom Teamcity logical branch name for target with multiple VCS Roots

Tags: git, teamcity

I have a build which consumes source code from **two** git repositories. The first vcs root contains reusable build scripts from the *master* branch of a git repository. The second vcs root contains the code I'm compiling from a *develop* branch in a different vcs root and different git repository from the first.

In the teamcity UI, my build shows as having run on a *default* branch. How can I configure teamcity to show the *develop* branch (from the second vcs root) as the logical branch name since this is really the branch name that makes most sense for developers looking at the teamcity UI.

I am running TeamCity 8.1.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted this same issue on JetBrain's youtrack website and according to TeamCity devs it cannot be done in the current version.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-40664

Answer (score 0):

Teamcity shows the "branch name" if you have a variable for branch name which is used in the "VCS settings " for your first repo. There are 2 things to understand here

1. If you do not want the branch name for the first repo to be shown, hardcode it to a value rather than parameterising it.
2. Parameterize the branch name for the second repo.
3. In case, the develop branch is still not shown switch the order in which you have defined the "VCS roots" in your build targets

Comment: hi @Biswajit_86. My VCS root containing build scripts has a hardcoded default branch (master) and my other vcs root containing my code has parameter driven default branch (param value is "develop"). I've also switched the order of my VCS roots and I still get "default" showing up as the branch used in my builds.

Comment: @DavEvans, could you attach snapshots of your config and display please